# Where/how are metals distributed in our universe?

Tags: metal, element

For one particular kind of element, what is the distribution in the whole universe?

Are most of the metals located in ISM, IGM, or stars? Maybe different metals have different distributions?
For example, could most of the Mg be found in white dwarfs?
Have *all* the natural elements have been found in stars?

Comment: Just for clarity, what do you mean by "metals"? Do you mean the chemical definition or the astronomical use, which is that everything other that hydrogen and helium are metals?

Comment: @FJC every kind of  element  except H

Answer (score 7):

From the [big bang nucleosynthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis) (BBN) page is a handy chart of the sources of elements:

[image]

Since basically all metals come from some stellar process, the question of elemental distribution can vary greatly between different environments depending on when you're observing that particular galaxy, star/galaxy cluster, etc. Galaxy mergers, supernova, and stellar winds can be particularly good at moving metals around a galaxy or galaxy cluster.

Interestingly Wolfram has element data with [Universe abundances](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ElementData.html) but I'm not sure where they derive those.

Comment: I revised my post in order to make it clear. My question for one kind of metal element, what is its distribution? Different metals should have different positions.